# How to get qrcode with qrcode 0.3 Grails Plugin

Tags: grails

I have some problem to activate qrcode 0.3 plugin. I already install on my project, and how to get print qrcode?

This is my code

```
def beforeInsert() {
    Integer count = Batch.count()+1
    String bc = sprintf('%04d',count)
    if( packNoLevel1 != null){
    number = prodDate.format('MM/dd/yy') + '/' + packNoLevel1 + '/' + item.code + '/' + bc
    }else{
    number = prodDate.format('MM/dd/yy') + '/' + packNoLevel2 + '/' + item.code + '/' + bc
    }
```

and how to generate number to qrcode ??
thanks..

Answer (score 1):

First is this `beforeInsert` an event in your domain? If so generating qr inside your domain does not help with rendering it.  Either you need to move that logic into your controller or save that number in database and use it later from a controller when you want to display the qrcode.

I assumed you were able to move the logic into a controller then you just need to pass that number into your view and the view will render the qrCode for you based on that number.

YourController.groovy

```
 def show() {

        // this logic needs be tweaked if you decide to have it in controller
        //Integer count = Batch.count()+1
        //String bc = sprintf('%04d',count)
        // if( packNoLevel1 != null){
        //     number = prodDate.format('MM/dd/yy') + '/' + packNoLevel1 + '/' + item.code + '/' + bc
        // }else{
        //    number = prodDate.format('MM/dd/yy') + '/' + packNoLevel2 + '/' + item.code + '/' + bc
        // }

        def number = calculateMe()
        [...,qrNumber:number]
 }
```

list.gsp

```
<qrcode:image text="${qrNumber}"/>
```